# Java AES CBC Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes

PHP Encrypt Function

```
$privateKey = "1234567812345678";
$iv = "1234567812345678";
$data = "Test string";

$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $privateKey, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo(base64_encode($encrypted));

Result: iz1qFlQJfs6Ycp+gcc2z4w==
```

When I try to decrypt this result in Java using the function below, all I get back is ì�š@ÔBKxnfÈ~¯Ô'M  while I am expecting "Test string". Any ideas where I am wrong? Thanks

```
public static String decrypt() throws Exception{
    try{
        String Base64EncodedText = "iz1qFlQJfs6Ycp+gcc2z4w==";
        String decodedText = com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.Base64.base64Decode(Base64EncodedText);
        String key = "1234567812345678";
        String iv = "1234567812345678";

        javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec keyspec = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec ivspec = new javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

        javax.crypto.Cipher cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decodedText.getBytes());

        String str = new String(decrypted);

        return str;

    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Java AES CBC Encryption Different Results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842509/php-java-aes-cbc-encryption-different-results)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EDIT: As of Java 8 Java now includes an acceptable Base64 class, [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).

---

This line

```
String decodedText = com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.Base64.base64Decode(Base64EncodedText);
```

looks wrong. Instead, use the [apache commons codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) classes or the [Harder base64](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) class. Also the default padding used by mcrypt, zero padding, is arguably wrong and makes it difficult to use the results in other languages. The users comments section for the [mcrypt_encrypt web pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) has examples of how to do this.

Here is small example that uses the apache commons classes to decrypt your string.

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class AESToy3 {

    private static final Charset ASCII = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String base64Cipher = "iz1qFlQJfs6Ycp+gcc2z4w==";
        byte [] cipherBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64Cipher);
        byte [] iv = "1234567812345678".getBytes(ASCII);
        byte [] keyBytes = "1234567812345678".getBytes(ASCII);

        SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NOPADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
        System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(result));
    }

}
```

this produces the following output:

```
5465737420737472696e670000000000
```

which when decoded as ASCII and removing the trailing zeros gives you `Test string`

Comment: Voted up first, before close :)

Comment: Thanks a lot GregS. Very well explained.

Comment: Thanks. But key is a different thing than IV - cloning them you just confuses readers.