# PHP Java AES CBC Encryption Different Results

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

PHP Function:

```
$privateKey = "1234567812345678";
$iv = "1234567812345678";
$data = "Test string";

$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $privateKey, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo(base64_encode($encrypted));

Result: iz1qFlQJfs6Ycp+gcc2z4w==
```

---

Java Function

```
public static String encrypt() throws Exception{
try{
    String data = "Test string";
    String key = "1234567812345678";
    String iv = "1234567812345678";

    javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec keyspec = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
    javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec ivspec = new javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

    javax.crypto.Cipher cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());

    return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypted);

}catch(Exception e){
    return null;
}
```

}

returns null.

Please note that we are not allowed to change the PHP code. Could somebody please help us get the same results in Java? Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd have had a better idea of what was going on if you didn't simply swallow up possible `Exception`s inside your `encrypt()` routine.  If your function is returning `null` then clearly an exception happened and you need to know what it was.

In fact, the exception is:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:854)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:828)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at Encryption.encrypt(Encryption.java:20)
    at Encryption.main(Encryption.java:6)
```

And sure enough, your plaintext is only 11 Java characters long which, in your default encoding, will be 11 bytes.

You need to check what the PHP `mcrypt_encrypt` function actually does.  Since it works, it is clearly using some padding scheme.  You need to find out which one it is and use it in your Java code.

Ok -- I looked up the man page for `mcrypt_encrypt`.  It says:

> The data that will be encrypted with the given cipher and mode. If the size of the data is not `n * blocksize`, the data will be padded with `\0`.

So you need to replicate that in Java.  Here's one way:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Encryption
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(encrypt());
    }

    public static String encrypt() throws Exception {
        try {
            String data = "Test string";
            String key = "1234567812345678";
            String iv = "1234567812345678";

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();

            // We need to pad with zeros to a multiple of the cipher block size,
            // so first figure out what the size of the plaintext needs to be.
            byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes();
            int plaintextLength = dataBytes.length;
            int remainder = plaintextLength % blockSize;
            if (remainder != 0) {
                plaintextLength += (blockSize - remainder);
            }

            // In java, primitive arrays of integer types have all elements
            // initialized to zero, so no need to explicitly zero any part of
            // the array.
            byte[] plaintext = new byte[plaintextLength];

            // Copy our actual data into the beginning of the array.  The
            // rest of the array is implicitly zero-filled, as desired.
            System.arraycopy(dataBytes, 0, plaintext, 0, dataBytes.length);

            SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

            return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypted);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run that I get:

```
iz1qFlQJfs6Ycp+gcc2z4w==
```

which is what your PHP program got.

---

**Update (12 June 2016)**:
As of Java 8, JavaSE finally ships with a documented base64 codec.  So instead of

```
return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypted);
```

you should do something like

```
return Base64.Encoder.encodeToString(encrypted);
```

Alternatively, use a 3rd-party library (such as `commons-codec`) for base64 encoding/decoding rather than using an undocumented internal method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, QuantumMechanic. Very well explained.

Comment: Note that zero based padding is normally not used, as you cannot distinguish between zero valued bytes at the end of the data and the padding. You should use PKCS#7 padding instead (`"PKCS5Padding"` in Java). Also note that using sun.* functionality fails all Java compatibility guidelines.