# Laravel Encryption, iOS Android Decryption

Tags: php, android, ios, laravel, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt some data using crypt::encrypt in Laravel. I need to decrypt this encryption in iOS and Android apps. Any idea?

Comment: I would make a request to the laravel app in HTTPS to decrypt using crypt::decrypt. Otherwise, if you provide some decryption technique on the client side, I think that would be a huge security mistake. However, I am not a professional

Comment: **Laravel's encrypter uses OpenSSL to provide AES-256 and AES-128 encryption** So you need to decrypt it in your apps the same way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627863/decrypt-aes256-encrypted-bytes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072021/aes-encrypt-and-decrypt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decrypt in Java (Android) text that was encrypted with Crypt in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975822/how-to-decrypt-in-java-android-text-that-was-encrypted-with-crypt-in-laravel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: **it is a bad idea, do not do it.**

A little more detailed:
It makes no sense. Laravel uses AES for encryption, which is a symmetric key algorithm: the same key is required for encryption and decryption. If you want to decrypt anything on the client side, you need the key to be known to the client - this basically renders the whole server-side encryption useless. To give advice on what to do instead, we need to know what you're trying to achieve:

- To transport the data securely between the Laravel-based server and the app? Use HTTPS.
- For anything else, the most likely answer is to use asymmetric encryption like RSA.

Comment: A better solution might be to encrypt the file on the server with a public key generated by the client: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php And decrypt it with the private key known by the client.